# Tab bar visible for all activities in android

Tags: android, tabbar, visible

My app contains 15 activities but i add only 3 activities for my tab bar.Tab Bar is visible in those activities not all. How to set tab bar visibility for all 15 screens or activities.

Comment: Please refer this `http://blog.uncommons.org/2011/04/18/scrolling-tabs-in-android/`

Comment: thanks...but my problem is not scroll tab bar. 3 tab bar should visible all the app(fixed for all screens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Created one Group Activity called TAB GROUP. It helps to display the Tab bar for whole 
app.

Comment: hello plz tell me the solution i have same problem

Answer (score 0):

Use HorizontalScrollView in layout xml

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/scroller"
        android:padding="0dp" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }
    LinearLayout theLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
        R.layout.tab_frag1_layout, container, false);
    // Register for the Button.OnClick event
    Button b = (Button) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.btn_startActivity);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(Tab1Fragment.this.getActivity(),
                "open new activity with tab bar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Here I want to start new activity with tab bar
        }
    });
    return theLayout;
    // return (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag1_layout,
    // container, false);
}
```